# C++ Struct Initialization with Inline If Statements Per Variable

Tags: c++, struct, c++17

I am trying to initialize an optional structure. Such that I would like to ideally have multiple if statements per variable. For example this is my current code;

```
struct FooBar {
  myObj1 foo;
  std::optional<myObj2> bar;
};

static std::optional<FooBar> globalFoo;

void Set(std::optional<int> x, std::optional<int> y)
{
    if (x && y)
    {
        globalFoot = FooBar{ .foo = {*x}, .bar = {*y} };
    }
    else if (x && !y)
    {
        globalFoot = FooBar{ .foo = {*x} };
    }
    else if (!x && y)
    {
        globalFoot = FooBar{.bar = {*y} };
    }
}
```

and I would like to somehow simplify this to

```
void Set(std::optional<int> x, std::optional<int> y)
{
    globalFoot = FooBar{ /* if x.has_value()*/ .foo = {x}, /* if y.has_value() */ .bar = {y} };
}
```

I am open to other suggestions, however the `Set` function must have optional inputs and the global variable as well.

Comment: `globalFoo = FooBar{ .foo = {x.value_or({})}, .bar = {y.value_or({})} };`?

Comment: Your current code doesn't guarantee an assignment to `globalFoot` / `globalFoo` (typo?).  Replacing it with a single assignment won't be able to replicate the same logic.

Comment: Seems for `y`, we need, instead of [`value_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or), [`optional::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform) (C++23) but free function can replace it before.

Comment: `value_or` is a decent option. However I forgot to mention I need to do a bit more operations on this. For example 

`globalFoot = FooBar{ .foo = {*x + i}, .bar = {*y + i *2} };`

Comment: Then look at [`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/transform)/ [`and_then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then) (or rewrite them as free function) should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things, I would probably make less use of `std::optional`.  You can perhaps use special values like 0 or -1 stored in the integers, or separate boolean flags.  You can write directly to those integers and booleans instead of making a `Set` function.  But that is just my opinion and I don't know all your requirements or what this code actually is used for.

If we assume that your global variables and interface are designed exactly the way you want them to be, and you just want a way to simplify your `Set` function without changing its behavior, here's what you can do:

```cpp
#include <optional>

struct FooBar {
  int foo;
  std::optional<int> bar;
};

static std::optional<FooBar> globalFoo;

void Set(std::optional<int> x, std::optional<int> y)
{
    if (!x && !y) { return; }
    globalFoo = {};
    if (x) { globalFoo->foo = *x; }
    globalFoo->bar = y;
}
```

(By the way, `myObj1` and `myObj2` are not defined in your question so it was not super clear what those are.  I just assumed they were both other names for `int`.)

The way the code was going before, you were going to have a combinatorial explosion of cases to express.  Now we just have a little bit of simple code to set each member instead of separately considering all those cases.